# Disable mouse drag to select

Tags: frames, mouse, fullscreen

I often run into an issue where I will click in a Emacs frame to make it active and accidentally slide my cursor so that it changes from a click to a drag. This means that some text is highlighted which can change behavior of the next commands I run (I am using `evil-mode`, so this puts me into visual state, but this is applicable outside of evil mode as well).

I don't want to completely disable the mouse, as I find it quite useful I just want to disable selecting text on a drag operation. I tried the following, but it lead to weird behavior (when the pointer leaving frames it will select text and it will still select one character sometimes).

`(define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] 'ignore)`

Is there a way to accomplish disabling drag to select (in evil specifically or outside)?

Comment: Because I have emacs full screen (with multiple monitors) and so there is no title bar or edge :)

Comment: Also I will often click on the window I want to select.

Comment: I find the `down-mouse-1` binding confusing.  Perhaps https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64966/454 helps to clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the point on click but *not* set the region on drag.

You can enable this behaviour globally with:

```
(progn
  (global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-set-point)
  (global-unset-key [down-mouse-1])
  (global-unset-key [drag-mouse-1]))
```

Comment: Why unbind `down-mouse-1`?