# Difference between [mouse-1] and [down-mouse-1]

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

I noticed two keys: `[mouse-1]` and `[down-mouse-1]`.

When I use `describe-key` with a single click, it shows:

```
There were several key-sequences:

  <down-mouse-1> at that spot runs the command evil-mouse-drag-region
  <mouse-1> at that spot runs the command mouse-set-point
```

If I want to bind a function to a single click event, which key is better?

Besides, when clicking the mouse, how to only trigger a single key sequence, either `<down-mouse-1>` or `<mouse-1>` but not both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`down-mouse-1` is a "button-down" event which is generated immediately when you press the mouse button.

`mouse-1` is a "click" event, which is generated if you release the button at the same position as the "button-down" event.

`drag-mouse-1` is a "drag" event which would be generated if you released the button at a different position.

You can learn about these and more at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Input Events`