# `define-key` redefines behavior of slow mouse click, but not fast mouse click

Tags: key-bindings, mouse, events, timestamped

## The problem in brief

I want to redefine what clicking (on an `org` link) does. My code works, if I click slowly enough, but for a normal (fast) click it does not -- instead I get the default behavior. Changing ordinary keyboard shortcuts in the `org-mode` `keymap` works fine.

[Sidenote: If I could instead change the behavior of `org-open-at-point`, to call `delete-other-windows` after running, that would be a more natural, if less declarative, solution.]

I'm finding nothing in the Emacs docs about click duration, although I do see that [events have timestamps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html).

## My code, and the reasoning behind it

I've tried both of the following:

```
(define-key org-mode-map [mouse-1]         'jbb-org-open-at-point)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'jbb-org-open-at-point)
```

Both have the same effect. Slow-clicking on a link runs `jbb-org-open-at-point`, like I hoped, but fast-clicking runs the default `org-open-at-point`.

Thanks to @Drew I understand that `mouse-1` represents releasing the button, and `down-mouse-1` represents pressing the button. Since I want to preserve the default `down-mouse-1` behavior, which is to move the cursor to wherever the mouse is, I'm not mentioning `down-mouse-1` in my code.

I tried replacing `mouse-1` in the above code with `up-mouse-1`. That was no good -- short clicks still had the default behavior, but long clicks had no effect.

## Details that might not be important

### My definition of `jbb-org-open-at-point`

It's just like  `org-open-at-point`,
except the new buffer occupies the entire window,
rather than half of it.
It does nothing if `org-mode` is not the major mode.

```
(defun jbb-org-open-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (if ;; TODO ? Maybe I should simplify this.
      ;; This if-else clause testing the major mode is unnecessary,
      ;; because `jbb-org-open-at-point`
      ;; will only be called via the shortcut defined next,
      ;; which is only available from org-mode.
      (equal "org-mode" (symbol-name major-mode))
      (progn (call-interactively 'org-open-at-point)
         (delete-other-windows))
    (message ("jbb-org-open-at-point does nothing outside of org-mode."))
))
```

### Remapping keyboard (as opposed to mouse) shortcuts works as expected

I can successfully redefine `C-c C-o` in the  `org-mode` keyboard map,
so that it uses the new `jbb-org-open-at-point`
instead of the default `org-open-at-point`:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-o")   'jbb-org-open-at-point)
```

I know that works because after doing that,
if I type `C-c C-o` while the cursor is on an `org` link,
the new buffer occupies the entire window, rather than half of it.

Answer (score 2):

A mouse click results in multiple events.

If you want the action to take place upon the button press, and the button-release to be ignored, you can use this, for example:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map [down-mouse-1] 'jbb-org-open-at-point)
(define-key org-mode-map [mouse-1]      'ignore)
```

Or if you want the action to take place upon release and the press to be ignored, then reverse those two "keys".

Also, your command needs to have an `interactive` spec that corresponds to a mouse event - something like this:

```lisp
(defun jbb-org-open-at-point (_event)
  "..."
  (interactive "e") ; Event is ignored.
  ...)
```

Your code seems to ignore the mouse event, beyond the fact of it happening.  But if, for example, you wanted to use the mouse-point position and not `point`, then you could use something like this:

```lisp
(defun jbb-org-open-at-point (event)
  "..."
  (interactive "e")
  (let* ((mouse-pos  (event-start event))
         (mouse-win  (posn-window mouse-pos))
         (mouse-pt   (posn-point  mouse-pos)))
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer mouse-win)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char mouse-pt)
        ... ; do stuff at click position
   ...))))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Accessing Mouse](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Mouse.html).

Comment: Related Q&A: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64964/difference-between-mouse-1-and-down-mouse-1

Comment: Thanks, Drew! (I can't seem to @ you.) It's more complicated than I thought. Today I edited my OP to reflect the discovery, which you led me to, that my code works if I click slowly. The `org-mode` `keymap` appears to move point to where the click happened on mouse-down, which behavior I still want, so I'm not defining any new behavior of `down-mouse-1`. When I modify the function definition to use `interactive "e"` and accept but ignore an `_event` argument, like you suggest, I see no change in behavior -- slow clicks still work, and fast (normal) clicks still don't.